# How to add a pure React project to an existing solution in Rider

Tags: rider

I have an existing solution with a few different .Net Web apps and class libraries on it. Our front end team is busy working on a new React / NextJS app that will run on Node.

I'd like to include this project into our Rider solution but it doesn't have a project file or anything like that. It's just a folder.

How do I do this?

I see I can create a "Project Folder" in Rider which I can nest actual .Net Web or library projects under. Is it possible to include this new folder under one of these?

I see there is an option when I right click on the folder to "Attach to solution". Is this what I'm looking for?

Thank you =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this kind of applications, Rider has an **Attach Existing Folder** action.

Right-click your solution, choose **Attach Existing Folder**, and then select a folder containing the frontend application sources.

It will be visible near the solution in the **Solution** view, and you'll be able to work on it normally (as you would if it was included into the solution).

[image: Solution view with an external attached folder]

Please note that an "Attached folder" is not the same as a "Solution folder" (since it isn't tied to the solution in any way, and cannot contain .NET project structure).

Answer (score 3):

For anyone still reading this, there i another way which I find better, because you can exclude subfolders (for example node_modules).

Create a Project.njsproj file and use this as an example to populate it:

```xml
<Project>
    <Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\Node.js Tools\Microsoft.NodejsToolsV2.targets" />
    <PropertyGroup>
        <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
        <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
        <ProjectGuid>{1d5f9c22-57bc-4a29-8528-2b5b775c37f6}</ProjectGuid>
        <ProjectHome />
        <ProjectView>ShowAllFiles</ProjectView>
        <WorkingDirectory>.</WorkingDirectory>
        <OutputPath>.</OutputPath>
        <ProjectTypeGuids>{3AF33F2E-1136-4D97-BBB7-1795711AC8B8};{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{9092AA53-FB77-4645-B42D-1CCCA6BD08BD}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <Script Include="src/**/*" />
        <Script Include=".gitignore" />
        <Script Include=".eslintrc.cjs" />
        <Script Include="index.html" />
        <Script Include="package.json" />
        <Script Include="tsconfig.json" />
        <Script Include="tsconfig.node.json" />
        <Script Include="vite.config.ts" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Then add it as a project in the solution
[image: Njsproject]